# .NET cannot send SMS using sinch

Tags: c#, .net, sinch, sinch-rest-api

I am learning xamarin, I would like to send an sms using  [sinch](https://github.com/sinch/nuget-serversdk) but it is not working

I have this error : Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.'

Here is my code from the github in a console app:

```
    class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            MainAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }

        private static async Task MainAsync()
        {
            var smsApi = SinchFactory.CreateApiFactory("xxx", "xxxx","https://clientapi.sinch.com").CreateSmsApi(); 

            var sendSmsResponse =  await smsApi.Sms("+XXXXXXNumber", "Hello world.  Sinch SMS here.").Send(); // the error happens here

            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)); // May take a second or two to be delivered.

            var smsMessageStatusResponse = await smsApi.GetSmsStatus(sendSmsResponse.MessageId);
            Console.WriteLine(smsMessageStatusResponse.Status);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

if there is a way to use sinch I ll take

Thanks in advance

Comment: In which line does the exception happen? My first thought is that maybe the key and the secret you pass to the Factory are not correct?

Comment: @devcrp in this line   var smsApi = SinchFactory.CreateApiFactory("xxx", "xxxx").CreateSmsApi();

Comment: if I put a wrong key and secret I have this error "System.ArgumentException: 'Sinch application key is in an invalid format.  Confirm the key is correctly copied from your Sinch developer dashboard.'" So the error is not about the key and secret

Comment: @devcrp i have update the code now the error is Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.'